# How can I set precision when printing a PyTorch tensor with integers?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have:

```
mask = mask_model(input_spectrogram)
mask = torch.round(mask).float()
torch.set_printoptions(precision=4)
print(mask.size(), input_spectrogram.size(), masked_input.size())
print(mask[0][-40:], mask[0].size())
```

This prints:

```
tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0.], grad_fn=<SliceBackward>) torch.Size([400])
```

But I want it to print `1.0000` instead of `1.`. Why won't my `set_precision` do it? Even when I converted to `float()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is simply how PyTorch displays tensor values. Your code works fine, if you do `print(mask * 1.1)`, you can see that PyTorch does indeed print out 4 decimal values when the tensor values can no longer be represented as integers.